# Circle label alignment

Tags: html, css

[image]

Trying to put a green box/circle after my radio button label or just before the label. Either one would work.

```html
<div class="box green" ></div>
<input type="radio" id="radioOne" value="Y"/> <label>Verified Yes</label>
```

I know this is supposed to be easy with CSS but if I use display: inline in the css for the radio button, the circles disappear, beyond that I'm only able to place the circles in the line above or below the radio button.

Comment: Can you show the CSS code as well? Have you tried `inline-block`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box green"></div>
<input type="radio" id="radioOne" value="Y"/>
<label>
  Verified Yes <div class="box-green"></div>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
.box-green {
  display:       inline-block;
  width:         1em;
  height:        1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:    #00FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block`, like:

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radioOne" value="Y"/> <label>Verified Yes <span class="box green"></span></label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="radioTwo" value="Y"/> <label><span class="box green"></span> Verified Yes</label>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should provide the CSS, etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/3n1n0y05/

Chances are you're just forgetting to set a width/height or content

```
#radioOne + label:before {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#radioOne:checked + label:before {
  background: green;
}
```